# it just gets too hot . any way of cooling it?

Tags: arduino-mega, atmega2560, heat, led-matrix

there i just got started with the arduino mega2560 . i tried 8x8 matrix tube and after ~30secs i found the atmega2560 a bit hot that i can melt a small amount wax on it ! is there any sort of heatsink or a better way to use the matrix tube ? what i have done is to turn on a led is to turn on the positive side and turn off the negative side . i just tried that method because in my 1st beginner kit , the manual said this should be done incase of a common anode rgb led .

thanks alot

Comment: An Atmega should never get that hot. You are definitely going something wrong. Please provide a schematic or wiring diagram of your project. Are you providing the LEDs with power through the IO ports? Or do you use any kind of driver?

Comment: well that is just a phrase . i really don't know if it can melt wax .

Comment: Doesn't really matter. An Atmega should never get warm by itself. It doesn't incorporate powerful hardware like the ESP (which geta a bit warm, when using wifi). If it gets warm, you are doing something wrong. For example the outputs are only do provide signal, not power. Each pin can only provide 20mA of current. And as I remember the overall IO current is limited to 100mA. With 8x8=64 LEDs you can easily exceed that

Comment: @Raj interesting how different parts of the world have different expressions ... it is `you could fry an egg on it` here